# Why supervisorctl ERROR (no such process)?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to install supervisorctl to use for my laravel queue command but having issues  ERROR (no such process) here is my supervisord.conf I have tried all the reload,reread and restart and still no success process when trying to start my process

```
'; Sample supervisor config file.
;
; For more information on the config file, please see:
; http://supervisord.org/configuration.html
;
; Notes:
;  - Shell expansion ("~" or "$HOME") is not supported.  Environment
;    variables can be expanded using this syntax: "%(ENV_HOME)s".
;  - Quotes around values are not supported, except in the case of
;    the environment= options as shown below.
;  - Comments must have a leading space: "a=b ;comment" not "a=b;comment".
;  - Command will be truncated if it looks like a config file comment, e.g.
;    "command=bash -c 'foo ; bar'" will truncate to "command=bash -c 'foo ".

[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock   ; the path to the socket file
chmod=0700                 ; socket file mode (default 0700)
;chown=nobody:nogroup       ; socket file uid:gid owner
;username=user              ; default is no username (open server)
;password=123               ; default is no password (open server)

;[inet_http_server]         ; inet (TCP) server disabled by default
;port=127.0.0.1:9001        ; ip_address:port specifier, *:port for all iface
;username=user              ; default is no username (open server)
;password=123               ; default is no password (open server)

[supervisord]
logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log ; main log file; default $CWD/supervisord.log
logfile_maxbytes=50MB        ; max main logfile bytes b4 rotation; default 50MB
logfile_backups=10           ; # of main logfile backups; 0 means none, default 10
loglevel=info                ; log level; default info; others: debug,warn,trace
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid ; supervisord pidfile; default supervisord.pid
nodaemon=false               ; start in foreground if true; default false
minfds=1024                  ; min. avail startup file descriptors; default 1024
minprocs=200                 ; min. avail process descriptors;default 200
;umask=022                   ; process file creation umask; default 022
;user=chrism                 ; default is current user, required if root
;identifier=supervisor       ; supervisord identifier, default is 'supervisor'
;directory=/tmp              ; default is not to cd during start
;nocleanup=true              ; don't clean up tempfiles at start; default false
;childlogdir=/tmp            ; 'AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP
;environment=KEY="value"     ; key value pairs to add to environment
;strip_ansi=false            ; strip ansi escape codes in logs; def. false

; The rpcinterface:supervisor section must remain in the config file for
; RPC (supervisorctl/web interface) to work.  Additional interfaces may be
; or inet_http_server section.

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket
;serverurl=http://127.0.0.1:9001 ; use an http:// url to specify an inet socket
;username=chris              ; should be same as in [*_http_server] if set
;password=123                ; should be same as in [*_http_server] if set
;prompt=mysupervisor         ; cmd line prompt (default "supervisor")
;history_file=~/.sc_history  ; use readline history if available

; The sample program section below shows all possible program subsection values.
; Create one or more 'real' program: sections to be able to control them under
; supervisor.

;[program:theprogramname]
;command=/bin/cat              ; the program (relative uses PATH, can take args)
;process_name=%(program_name)s ; process_name expr (default %(program_name)s)
;numprocs=1                    ; number of processes copies to start (def 1)
;directory=/tmp                ; directory to cwd to before exec (def no cwd)
;umask=022                     ; umask for process (default None)
;priority=999                  ; the relative start priority (default 999)
;autostart=true                ; start at supervisord start (default: true)
;startsecs=1                   ; # of secs prog must stay up to be running (def. 1)
;startretries=3                ; max # of serial start failures when starting (default 3)
;autorestart=unexpected        ; when to restart if exited after running (def: unexpected)
;exitcodes=0,2                 ; 'expected' exit codes used with autorestart (default 0,2)
;stopsignal=QUIT               ; signal used to kill process (default TERM)
;stopwaitsecs=10               ; max num secs to wait b4 SIGKILL (default 10)
;stopasgroup=false             ; send stop signal to the UNIX process group (default false)
;killasgroup=false             ; SIGKILL the UNIX process group (def false)
;user=chrism                   ; setuid to this UNIX account to run the program
;redirect_stderr=true          ; redirect proc stderr to stdout (default false)
;stdout_logfile=/a/path        ; stdout log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
;stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
;stdout_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stdout logfile backups (0 means none, default 10)
;stdout_capture_maxbytes=1MB   ; number of bytes in 'capturemode' (default 0)
;stdout_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stdout writes (default false)
;stderr_logfile=/a/path        ; stderr log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
;stderr_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
;stderr_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stderr logfile backups (0 means none, default 10)
;stderr_capture_maxbytes=1MB   ; number of bytes in 'capturemode' (default 0)


; The sample eventlistener section below shows all possible eventlistener
; subsection values.  Create one or more 'real' eventlistener: sections to be
; able to handle event notifications sent by supervisord.

;[eventlistener:theeventlistenername]
;command=/bin/eventlistener    ; the program (relative uses PATH, can take args)
;process_name=%(program_name)s ; process_name expr (default %(program_name)s)
;numprocs=1                    ; number of processes copies to start (def 1)
;events=EVENT                  ; event notif. types to subscribe to (req'd)
;buffer_size=10                ; event buffer queue size (default 10)
;directory=/tmp                ; directory to cwd to before exec (def no cwd)
;umask=022                     ; umask for process (default None)
;priority=-1                   ; the relative start priority (default -1)
;autostart=true                ; start at supervisord start (default: true)
;startsecs=1                   ; # of secs prog must stay up to be running (def. 1)
;startretries=3                ; max # of serial start failures when starting (default 3)
;autorestart=unexpected        ; autorestart if exited after running (def: unexpected)
;exitcodes=0,2                 ; 'expected' exit codes used with autorestart (default 0,2)
;stopsignal=QUIT               ; signal used to kill process (default TERM)
;stopwaitsecs=10               ; max num secs to wait b4 SIGKILL (default 10)
;stopasgroup=false             ; send stop signal to the UNIX process group (default false)
;killasgroup=false             ; SIGKILL the UNIX process group (def false)
;user=chrism                   ; setuid to this UNIX account to run the program
;redirect_stderr=false         ; redirect_stderr=true is not allowed for eventlisteners
;stdout_logfile=/a/path        ; stdout log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
;stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
;stdout_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stdout logfile backups (0 means none, default 10)
;stdout_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stdout writes (default false)
;stderr_logfile=/a/path        ; stderr log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
;stderr_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
;stderr_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stderr logfile backups (0 means none, default 10)
;stderr_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stderr writes (default false)
;environment=A="1",B="2"       ; process environment additions
;serverurl=AUTO                ; override serverurl computation (childutils)

; The sample group section below shows all possible group values.  Create one
; or more 'real' group: sections to create "heterogeneous" process groups.

;[group:thegroupname]
;programs=progname1,progname2  ; each refers to 'x' in [program:x] definitions
;priority=999                  ; the relative start priority (default 999)

; The [include] section can just contain the "files" setting.  This
; setting can list multiple files (separated by whitespace or

; newlines).  It can also contain wildcards.  The filenames are
; interpreted as relative to this file.  Included files *cannot*
; include files themselves.

[include]
files = conf.d/*.ini
;files = conf.d/*.conf '
```

and here is my process conf file. although i have called it easyschools.ini

```
[program:easyschools]

process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d

command=php /home/rayes/dashboard/artisan queue:work

autostart=true

autorestart=true

user=rayes

numprocs=3

redirect_stderr=true

stdout_logfile=/home/rayes/dashboard /queue-worker.log
```

Comment: I had this issue and in my case the command was a bash script where I had a #!/bin/bash to the top.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I assume you saved the supervisord configuration under `/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf`, you should first start `supervisord` process with the specified configuration, then control it with `supervisorctl`:

**Commands:**

```
> supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
> supervisorctl reread
> supervisorctl update
> supervisorctl start easyschools:*
```

Also make sure not to have any extra space/newline in your process configuration:

```
[program:easyschools]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /home/rayes/dashboard/artisan queue:work
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=rayes
numprocs=3
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/rayes/dashboard/queue-worker.log
```

Comment: I have followed your suggestions and again received the same error. please check the photo attachment 
https://ibb.co/YQvmLHp

Comment: From your screenshot you can see that your process configuration file still contains a space in the stdout_logfile property. Remove that to have a correct path where to store your logfile.

Comment: Also before running any other instance of supervisors, make sure to kill the previous one by running `supervisorctl shutdown`. Then follow the steps I wrote in my answer. Note that the process name to start is followed by `:` not `.`

Comment: I solved the issue. i found another configuration file for supervisor in the etc directory. I changed the location of include files and it worked. Thank you